# list() definition TypeError

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem while creating an empty list in Python3.6.3 with **list()** (I work with Pycharm - community 2019.3)

The strange thing is that if I do it in terminal (or if I clear all the script code but this line) it works, but if I use the same line in a script, it's highlighted as an error and running it would lead to *TypeError: 'list' object is not callable*

The code up to the point it fails is is:

```
list = open('intro.txt').read().split()
alph = "abcdefgjklmn'opqrstuvwxyz"
alph = alph + alph.upper()
clean_list = list()
```

The 4th line is the one that fails, and it does the same everytime I generate an empty list this way..

Btw I have no problem by doing **clean_list = [ ]** but this errror annoys me a lot

Thanks!

Comment: The first line of your code is overwriting the built-in `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a variable called "list" which Python won't like if used in the same script as `list()`. So try renaming the the first variable.